# Visual Studio indent without curly brackets

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, indentation

I have a very specific question regarding indentation of blocks on Visual Studio (I currently use its 2013 iteration). If I have something like this (code in C++):

```
  if (a)
    return d;
```

Visual Studio indents it correctly, i.e., by adding a tab in the following line to the if clause. Now — when presented with something like this:

```
  if (a)
    if (b) {
      c = c + a;
      return d;
    }
```

Visual Studio instead indents it like:

```
  if (a)
    if (b) {
    c = c + a;
    return d;
    }
```

This is not, indeed, something I'd like to see on my code. I know someone might come and say not having curly brackets around clauses can be considered as a bad programming habit, but that's my style of coding.

Does anyone know a way around that on Visual Studio? I believe I tried pretty much every option on the Text Editor preferences, without success.

Thank you!

Comment: I get it too on VS2013 Update 3. Have you submitted a bug to Microsoft?

Comment: One possible way to fix it is to use ClangFormat instead of the built in formatter?